# $3$. If the difference between the simple interest and compound interest on some principal amount at $20$% per annum for $3$ years is ` $48$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the difference between the simple interest and compound interest on some principal amount at
20% per annum for 3 years is ` 48, then the principle amount must be

My sol.: Let principle amount be x. I know how to calculate Simple interest i.e (P*R*T)/100 = x *20 * 3/100=60x/100. For compound interest, I calculated this way $(({x}+{20x}/100)*20/100 + ({x}+{20x}/100))*20/100$ This results in $({72x}/100)$

But this is wrong, please tell me what I've done wrong, I think we can calculate the compound interest in this way too. Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Which formula did you use for compound interest?

Comment: I didn't use any formula here I calculated manually and please explain why do you downvote my question?

Comment: Can you elaborate your manual calculations?

Comment: I'll prove by an example. Suppose principle amount is 100 and 10 % rate per annum and time = 2 years (Compound interest reckoned). 

So here the solution goes with the formula of compound interest: P(1+ R/100)^n=121

Solution with manual calculation using a percentage concept: (100*10/100+100)10/100+(100*10/100+100) =121

Comment: Here I calculated the actual amount after the compound interest. In a similar way, I've calculated the compound interest for 3 years. Please check.

Comment: -@Sanjay Verma, it is correct with slight error. Compound interest should be $\frac{72.8x}{100}$

Comment: Okay, thanks @SarGe,

Answer (score 1):

Given,
T = 3yrs
Rate. Interest = 20%
Principal = ?(Let's consider it as x)

$$\therefore S.I = \frac{x * T * R}{100}$$ $$\implies S.I = \frac{x * 3 * 20}{100}$$
$$\implies S.I = \frac{3x}{5}$$
$$\implies Amount on S.I = \frac{8x}{5}$$

$$\therefore Amount on C.I = x * (1 + \frac{Rate}{100})^T$$
$$\implies Amount on C.I = x * (1 + \frac{20}{100})^3$$
$$\implies Amount on C.I = x * (\frac{6}{5})^3$$
$$\implies Amount on C.I = \frac{216x}{125}$$

$$Amount on C.I  - Amount on S.I = P + C.I - P - S.I= C.I - S.I$$
$$\implies \frac{216x}{125} - \frac {8x}{5} = 48$$
$$\implies \frac{216x - 200x}{125} = 48$$

I hope You can do the rest on your own